# Bring up numpad on mobile devices without <input type="number">

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, webkit

I'm making a website that has input fields that should allow you to input a string such as this: "1-2*3+4". I also want to bring up the numpad for mobile devices.

```
<input type="number">
```

Does not work since webkit browsers invalidates the example above (since it contains signs). **Are there any alternatives for bringing up the numpad other than the one above?** (type="tel" doesn't contain the - sign)

EDIT:
So I found a workaround:

```
$('.myInput').focus(function(){
    $(this).get(0).type = 'text';
});
$('.myInput').blur(function(){
    $(this).get(0).type = 'number';
});
```

When the input gets focused I change the type to text (at least on iPhone this change happens after the numpad is already brought up). When it loses focus I change the type back to number so that it works again if the input gets focus again.

I'm still interested in other suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're stuck with either the numpad or the numeric keyboard with extra keys (which contains minus but not plus, unfortunately).

To achieve just the numpad:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

To achieve extended number keyboard:

```
<input type="number" pattern="*" />
```

Read more about this in Apple's [Safari Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008248-CH1-DontLinkElementID_14).

Comment: Hmm, the Safari Developer Library doesn't even mention type="number". But <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" /> brings up a simple numpad. I'm hoping there's a solution for type="text" that still gives the extended numpad.